# Tracing an image to produce a vector graphic

Tags: graphics

I have a line-drawing that I would like to trace into a vector graphic, but cannot find documentation on how to perform some of the basic graphic functions necessary to do this. Here is an example screenshot:

[image: sub line drawing]

Here I have pasted a line drawing of a submarine into a cell. I want to trace some of the lines from this drawing, add some new lines, then make some measurements using the scale in the drawing (20m).

To do this I tried first to lighten the image so it would be a very light gray--that way when I draw my vector line polygon I can clearly see it. Even better would be to change the color of black in the drawing to a pale yellow. Then it would be easy to see my black trace line. How can I lighten the drawing and/or change the color of the drawing from black to pale yellow?

For example, I tried using the "lighter" control shown in the screen shot, but it did not appear to do anything. I also tried using the "fill opacity" in the graphics toolbox (not shown), but that did not work either. (I think that must only apply to objects that I draw, not to pasted images.)

If I have a line I have drawn on top of the image, how can measure its length according to the scale in the drawing?

When I try to Binarize the image (according the answer below) it does not work for me, but produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Colorize` to make the black lines yellow (or any other color).

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/puUt5.png"];
Colorize[Binarize[img], ColorRules -> {0 -> Yellow, 1 -> White}]
```

[image]

Comment: If I paste an image into a cell, how do I refer to the object (get a handle to it), so I can apply a function like Colorize?

Comment: @TylerDurden Write something like `img = `, paste your picture after the equal sign, then evaluate. Also look at the [Generalized Input Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html#52003380).

Comment: This does not work for me. When I do this, the image is inverted and the background is yellow and the whole outline of the sub disappears.

Comment: Observe how I did it above: The command "img=  ... " sets img to be the name of the image. Then in the next line, this image is binarized and colorized. If you wish, copy/paste my code and it will work as above. If you want to work with a negative image, try `ColorNegate`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the yellow outline with the following expression:

```
ColorReplace[img, Black -> Lighter[Yellow, 0.6]]
```

This still leaves the problem of how to trace bezier curves on my object and then determine the length of particular lines. Eventually I gave up and did it in Adobe Illustrator. Kind of disappointing I could not do it in Mathematica.